# Creating an asset in Azure Media Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I am trying to create an asset in Azure from within my MVC 5 Web App and it is failing.

```
IAsset asset = context.Assets.Create("anynameyouwant", AssetCreationOptions.None);
IAccessPolicy writePolicy = context.AccessPolicies
                                   .Create("writePolicy", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120), AccessPermissions.Write);
ILocator destinationLocator = context.Locators
                                    .CreateLocator(LocatorType.Sas, asset, writePolicy);
```

My stack trace indicates that it's a issue with creating a token.

```
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.MediaServicesCredentials.<>c__DisplayClass9.<RefreshToken>b__4()
at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteAction>b__0()
at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)
at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Action action)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.MediaServicesCredentials.RefreshToken()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.OAuth.OAuthDataServiceAdapter.RefreshToken()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.OAuth.OAuthDataServiceAdapter.AddAccessTokenToRequest(WebRequest request)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AzureMediaServicesClassFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetAccountApiEndpoint>b__6()
```

I'm very new to Azure and I've spent the day trying to figure out how to solve this one, so if anyone could help me I'd be very grateful.

Comment: What's your error message, 400 or 401? What's your context? Pls paste more error message here, it is not difficult to create a asset in Media Services.

Comment: No it shouldn't be difficult but clearly I am the 1% that has a problem. All I get is a 400 error. Did you want to see more of the stack trace? Sorry, I'm very new to Azure and there are probably some gaps in my understanding.

Comment: Ok, learning some tutorial is good for you to get started with Azure, like that link Mehmet Aras provided. I place your code in [the sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-dotnet-on-demand-encoding-with-media-encoder-standard), no error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify MediaServicesCredentials in your code and configure access keys? Take a look at if not already [Get started with delivering content on demand using .NET SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-dotnet-get-started/). You can also check out [the error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn168949.aspx) to get some clues about the error you're getting.

Comment: I already checked the names and keys of my storage and media services accounts, if that's what you mean. It would seem that they have to meet certain rules such as being all lower case etc. All I get is a 400 error which is self explanatory, but I don't what exactly is causing it. I'll look at the link you sent. Thanks.